# R optparse: input and output file with the same prefix

Tags: r

I have a R script which calculates a plot based on the input data.

The input data and the output file should have the same filename, only the file extension should be different.

For instance, the R script should use the file `data.csv` and generate the plot `data.png`.

This however does not work:

```
library(optparse)

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-i", "--in_file"), type="character", default=NULL,
              help="input file", metavar="filename"),
  make_option(c("-o", "--out_file"), type="character",
              default=paste(opt$infile, ".png", sep=""),
              help="output file [default= %default]", metavar="filename")
  )

opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)
opt = parse_args(opt_parser)
```

This gives and error message because `opt` cannot be found (neither `data.png` nor `data.csv.png` are created).

```
Error in paste(opt$infile, ".png", sep = "") : object 'opt' not found
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT:** Forgot to copy two lines from the code, now the code is complete.

I understand that `opt` cannot be found because it is defined afterwards. However, my question still remains: How can I make sure that the output file has the same filename (with the exception of the extension) as the input file if no other value is given?

Comment: Where did you define `opt`?

Comment: Thank you, `opt` was the problem because it is defined after I tried to access it. My question however remains, see EDIT in question.

Comment: perhaps set the default to NULL, and later in the code use `if(is.null(opt$out_file)) opt$out_file <- gsub("\\.csv$", ".png", opt$in_file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> perhaps set the default to NULL, and later in the code use
>   if(is.null(opt$out_file)) opt$out_file <- gsub("\.csv$", ".png",
>   opt$in_file)

@baptiste: Thank you for the solution.

```
make_option(c("-o", "--out_file"), type="character",
            default=NULL, ...)
...
opt$out_file <- gsub("\\.csv$", ".png", opt$in_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is related, but "set" should be replaced by "sep" in your call to paste.